# create table in html as per the condition given for a table to mysql database table

Tags: php, html

I want to create a table(in HTML) which will display rows and columns where i am calling from my query statement i.e.,

`select id,name,city from contacts where enquiry_id=125`

which will display 3 to 4 rows of data having enquiry_id=125.

The result will be displayed in HTML format for PHP.(or HTML)..

Comment: Show us what have you tried.

Comment: [How to create HTML tables from MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690668/how-to-create-html-tables-from-mysql)

Comment: for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++) 
 {
 $condition="id=".$id.""; 
 $q1 = db_query('select *from '.PRE.$table.' where '.$condition);
 $id++; 

  if($row = @db_fetch_array($q1))
  { 
  $content .= "<tr>
  <td  valign=\"center\"> &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"contact_id[]\" name=\"contact_id[]\" value=\"".$row['id']."\"/></td>
  </tr>\n" ;    
  }  
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this and do not forget to connect to the database:

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    ?>

<tr>
    <td><?=$record['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?=$record['name']; ?></td>
      <td><?=$record['city']; ?></td>
</tr>    
<?
}

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank u ...Itz working .. but i made use of for loop.

Comment: Okay good its working then try to use the same codes with a for loop , another thing when the code works for you you upvote it

Comment: @Fred-ii- okay but I really get motivated from people like you who comes up and corect our mistakes thanks once again